# Static side menu with changing content

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like to create an app with a static side menu, which never changes and takes up 10% of the view.

In this menu a few options are available, when the user selects one of these, they go to a specific view, which is shown in the other 90% of the view, with the menu still being shown.

How can I switch a specific view in a page with another? How do I define these in a XAML file? Or do I need to place the menu on each of the pages I decide to use it on?

Comment: may help this http://blog.davemdavis.net/2012/10/03/simulating-a-tab-control-in-a-windows-8-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `<Frame Name="contentHolder" />`.

You can insert different `Page`s in this frame by using the `C#` code `contentHolder.Navigate(typeof(YourView));`